# How to send a word as a keypress event in JavaScript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to send a word like "admin" as a keypress event to an ID?

I want to send "admin" as a value inside;

```
document.getElementById("username").value;
```

When I send it as above, it is not working and looking for an event.

Best;

Comment: This feels like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you actually trying to accomplish? Why can you not just set the value? Why does it have to be a keypress event? Can you just send a keypress event after setting the value? You need to include more code in your question.

Comment: document.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(document.getElementById("username").value);
  }, 1000);
});

Comment: Hi Aplet123 the problem is that it is creating token after giving the values and do not accept the value property directly. So, it should be a key event.
@Parth thanks for the answer. It is very useful. However, it is not the answer. I do not wanna listen to the events, I want to give a username like "admin" and it will do that as in .value property but with event handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that worked for me :)

```
var sendcode = function(elementId,str){
    var elmnt = document.getElementById(elementId);
    var instr='';
    for(let chr of str){
    let kei = { key:chr,code:'Key'+chr.toUpperCase(), bubbles: true, composed: true, 
                cancelable: true, eventPhase: 3, isComposing: false, isTrusted: true, 
                view:document.defaultView, which:chr.charCodeAt(0)};       
                    
    instr += chr;
    let iei = { inputType:'insertText', data:instr, bubbles: true};
                    
    elmnt.value = instr;
    iev = new InputEvent('input',iei);
    elmnt.dispatchEvent(iev);
                    
    }
}

sendcode('username','admin');
sendcode('userpassword','password');
```